# Rails 5 Search filters multiple choice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, filter

I am trying to incorporate search filters on my search results page. After a user searches and the result are showcased on the search.html.erb I want them to use filters. The filters would be derived from the search results itself.

In other words I want to replicate what car gurus do. You search using make, model, price and then the filters would give you options for faceted search depending upon the search vehicle trim, transmission etc.

I tried single filter links like:

```
<%= addfilters "transmission", "Automatic" %>
```

and defining helper method like

```
def addfilters(column, title)
      link_to title, params.permit(:NewUsed, :category, :subcategory, :minprice, :maxprice, :location, :radius).merge({:"#{column}" => "Automatic"})
end
```

But how can I:

1. Use multiple select filters to fine tune search results I get from search form.
2. Populate these filter options using the search results, persist the results and merge new multiple values for params.
3. I want to get something like:

   [image: car gurus]

**I don't want to use external dependencies or gems like ransack or filterrific, I want to learn faceted search from scratch.**

If needed, my Search form code is:

```
<div id="Make" class="tabcontent1">
            <section class="formclass">

              <!-- f.select :transmission, ['Automanual','Automatic','Automatic 4 Speed','Automatic 5 Speed','Automatic 6 Speed','CVT','Manual'] -->
                <h3 style = "color:#F00000; text-align: center;"><strong><%= @carcount %> CARS LISTED!</strong></h3>

                <hr>

                <h3 style = "color:#7C064D;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <strong>SEARCH CARS FOR SALE BY MAKE</strong></h3>
                <%= form_tag search_listings_path, method: :get, class: 'navbar-form navbar-center' do |f| %>

                <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12"> 
                    <%= select_tag :NewUsed, "<option>New</option><option>Used</option>".html_safe, style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>

                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= select_tag :category, include_blank: true, style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>

                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= select_tag :subcategory, include_blank: true, style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">  -->
                    <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                        <%= text_field_tag :minprice, nil, placeholder: 'Min Price', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                        <%= text_field_tag :maxprice, nil, placeholder: 'Max Price', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= text_field_tag :location, nil, placeholder: 'Near', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>
                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= text_field_tag :radius, nil, placeholder: 'Radius', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>


                <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">              
                    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-danger', style: "width: 100%;" %>
                </div>
              <% end %>    
            </section>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A module like this would work

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end


#Controller
def index
  @products = Product.filter(params.slice(:status, :location, :over_price, :under_price))
end

#class Car < ApplicationRecord
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  include Filterable

  scope :status, -> (status) { where status: status }
  scope :location, -> (location_id) { where location_id: location_id }
  scope :over_price, -> (price) { where "price > ?", price) }
  scope :under_price, -> (price) { where "price < ?", price) }

  #continue adding more scopes here
end
```

Comment: Okay. But how to use aggregation/faceting like elasticsearch in sql and give users filters depending upon the search results in the view?

You search through a class method, and then you aggregate the search results in to groups and show it on the left like the pic above as well as show numbers in such aggregations on the right side so when selected the search results changes (Multiple can be selected as well).

Comment: You want to re-evaluate the query each time a new item is selected? You are going to have to use Ajax.

Comment: Also I think you need to make another question for that topic. That would make my answer very long and Im not sure i can answer everything adequately.

Comment: Yes. Every time the users hits search, he gets aggregations/facets with link to add that filter. Not the static scopes. The dynamically created filters which  if clicked adds more filtering to the given results. LIke in Transmission: automatic (5), manual (4) etc just like in the pic above

Comment: Again, I think you should ask that in a separate question.  That is a separate topic altogether an involves other components of your application. namely JS. Has my answer satisfied your current question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788349/jquery-select-menu-onchange-reevaluate-value

Comment: This looks like the method outlined by Justin Weiss here: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/. The article gives some context around why this approach was chosen and the author's rationale.